# Google Bar Chart max bar width

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a Google Bar Chart inside a fixed-width div. In some cases, I have many bars, but sometimes I only get 1 or 2 bars. The problem is that in this case, I got a chart like this:

[image]

I would like to set a max bar width, so that when I have only one bar, it doesn't take the whole container width. Do you know how to achieve that please?

[edit] I am looking for a solution for a **Material chart** (`google.charts.Bar`)

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. I think it has an effect when you have different bar groups, but in my case I have only one group.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a solution for a **Material chart** (`google.charts.Bar`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add blank columns when there are not enough columns initially.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        rows.push([" ", null])
    else
        rows.unshift([" ", null])
}
dataTable.addRows(rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

`bar.groupWidth` option **doesn't work** on *Material* charts

even with `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions`

tried versions `'41'` thru `'current'`

example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
    data.addRows([
      ['10h', 5]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({
      bar: {
        groupWidth: 20
      }
    }));
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**Edit**

only other option would be to modify the SVG directly when the chart's `'ready'` event fires
but this is not recommended

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
    data.addRows([
      ['10h', 5]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(container);

    // modify SVG on 'ready'
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var bars = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function(bar) {
        // reduce width by 50%
        bar.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(0.5,1)');
      });
    });

    chart.draw(data, {});
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, so how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following (inspired by @Amaud)

To prevent a bar-chart with one very thick row, I add blank rows using the following code

```
  if (tData.getNumberOfRows()==1) {
        addRow(tData,' ',1);
        addRow(tData,' ',1);
    }
```

The full code is as follows:

Note that the function addRow adds a row to the chart only if there is a value, therefore sometimes
there can be only one row which ends up being very thick.

```
var tData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
tData.addColumn('string','Type');
tData.addColumn('number','Amount (Millions)");
addRow(tData,'Row1', a1);
addRow(tData,'Row2', a2);   
addRow(tData,'Row3', a3);    
addRow(tData,'Row4', a4);
if (tData.getNumberOfRows()==1) {
    addRow(tData,' ',1);
    addRow(tData,' ',1);
  }

 var options = {
        ...
      };

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(tData, options);


function addRow(tData,text,num) {
   if (num>0) {
       tData.addRow([text,num/1000000]);
    }
}
```