# How to limit width of google bar chart when there is only 1 result?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

With multiple data entries, the chart looks great.

Example:
[image]

Now if I only have one input it looks like this:

[image]

I have looked at other articles and nothing is helping, I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082867/google-bar-chart-max-bar-width) and it seems to have worked for that user but I can't seem to implement it in my code.

Any help on limiting the width of the bars for a single entry would be greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['', 'Views'],
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT post_title, post_views_count FROM posts WHERE post_user = '{$username}' AND post_status = 'published' ORDER BY post_views_count DESC LIMIT 8";
      $select_views = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_views)) {
        $post_title = escape($row['post_title']);
        $post_views_count = escape($row['post_views_count']);

        echo "['$post_title'" . "," . "$post_views_count],";
      }
      ?>
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    colors: '#006135',
    axes: {
      x: {
        0: { side: 'bottom', label: ''} // Top x-axis.
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
  </script>
  <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 'auto'; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

other than modifying the chart's svg manually,
there aren't any style settings you can set,
as you've seen in the other answer

one option would be to modify the data
if there is only one row,
add a blank row before and after the real row

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', 'Views'],
    ['One Story For Last User', 5]
  ]);

  // add blank rows
  if (data.getNumberOfRows() === 1) {
    data.insertRows(0, [[' ', null]]);
    data.addRow([' ', null]);
  }

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    colors: '#006135'
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```